# Text view losing characters that is to be displayed [Android]

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a text to be displayed in a text view. The text contains 200 lines of data, each line is having 10 characters. So total **2000 characters**. The text view is inside a vertical scrollable view. **The first 50 lines are not getting displayed**. If the text view had a limitation to the number of characters, then its fair enough if it loses the last few lines, **but why is it taking off the head??**.
And also what is the limit on the number of characters for a text view??

[image: top most- missing first 50 lines of data]

[image: dragged down some more extra space available(can fit 50 lines i guess)]

My code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_layout_ECG"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_ECG"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_ECG"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_ECG"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvECG_samples"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="ECG\nsamples"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </ScrollView>
```

In the 1st screen shot, the data is being shown from 51st line. The first 50 lines are clipped off. Why??

Comment: can you show the screenshot?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the problem you have?

Comment: TextView are limited text are show.. if you want to show big data then textView not use

Answer (score 0):

no need of external scrollbar rather than u can use textview's property

```
                   android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

I think It will help u

Comment: Ya i know that way, but i just wanted to know what was going wrong here(while using a text view inside a scroll view...that's it).